# Restrict access from specific domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, ubuntu-12.04, vps

**We have two domains directed to one VPS server**, one of those domains is **not** ours and is messing the bussiness specially in google search. **Is there any possible way to restrict access from this domain with no harm to the second one?** Will that help google to put our main domain at the top? I spoke to a guy who has this domain, but he told me, that his bussiness just gone wild and his bussiness partner which took care of website just got "disappeared" (meaning ran away with the money), so he will not get access to domain settings.

It looks like our server provider just rent us the same server after it expired for that guy.

**I have full access to VPS, so what can I do? Is there any way to do it via htaccess or maybe something in ubuntu?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That might help you: [Apache redirect](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html)

Comment: Hosting providers won't give you someone else's old VPS. They will provision a new one. However you might be assigned the same IP address. If this other domain is still pointing to that IP nothing will come up if you don't have a site in Apache for it anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for reactions. I wrote to a support and they just removed the IP address from the old domain. Surprisingly they did not need from me to prove if I am owner or not. So it is solved, thank you.